# While Createing GRPC sever application getting Grpc.Core.RpcException

Tags: asp.net, grpc

Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.")'

This is Program.cs File

```
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace GrpcClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(String[] args)
        {
            

            var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5000", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
            var client = new Customer.CustomerClient(channel);
            CustomerRequest customerRequested = new CustomerRequest { Id = 1 };
            var response = await client.CustomerInfoAsync(customerRequested);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {response.Firstname}{Environment.NewLine}LastName: {response.Lastname} {Environment.NewLine}Age: {response.Age}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}


Customer.Proto 

syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcConsoleServer";

package greet;

service Customer
{
    rpc CustomerInfo(CustomerRequest) returns(CustomerResponse);
}

message CustomerRequest
{
    int32 Id=1;
}

message CustomerResponse
{
    string firstname=1;
    string lastname=2;
    int32 age=3;
}



CustomerService1.cs

using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace GrpcConsoleServer.Service
{
    public class CustomerService1:Customer.CustomerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CustomerService1> _logger;
        public CustomerService1(ILogger<CustomerService1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            
        }
        public override Task<CustomerResponse> CustomerInfo(CustomerRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            CustomerResponse response = new CustomerResponse();
            if(request.Id==1)
            {
                response.Firstname = "Deepa";
                response.Lastname = "Toravi";
                response.Age = 25;

            }
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```